# How to install dual-boot Ubuntu on ASUS F202E Notebook

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, asus

Have an almost 2-year old ASUS F202E notebook that came with Windows 8 and subsequently upgraded to Win 8.1.Since new, it has been a dog. 2GB of non-upgradable memory is nowhere near enough to run Win8.1.

I bought it with the intention of converting it to a dual boot Ubuntu machine, as I'd done this with on old Toshiba laptop and it'd been performing beautifully on Ubuntu for years but was hopeless with Windows XP.

I first attempted to try and boot Ubuntu from a USB drive. No go. Learned all about UEFI booting and after lots of swearing and failed attempts I gave up after contacting ASUS, who were no help at all.

I searched for forums and found a few descriptions of how others had run into the same issue on this machine but there were a number of horror stories from people who'd tried several techniques and read stories of the process corrupting the Windows partitions, failing to boot after install, "don't use WUBI", some say "Disable UEFI". Others say "Don't disable UEFI" etc. So I put it away again.

Still, to date, I can't seem to find online any method of doing this that anyone has confirmed will actually work reliably without stuffing up something seriously.

Anyone reading this who has actually done it on this machine and had it running reliably for any period of time?

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

if your just trying to boot off of the USB, go to system BIOS and enable CSM. you also need to put it into legacy mode.

Comment: Legend! I lost my USB boot option, and enabling CSM got it back, thanks!